# css navbar with different button styles

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox, bootstrap-sass

Hy everybody,

I try to build a navbar with sass that looks like this:

navbar with one row

[image]

So far i got the first row without problems:

The tricky thing at the second row is, when the navbar expands with another item the border-radius should align in the second row. See this example:

[image]

The sixths item should only have a border-radius at the bottom right.

Hope my explanation is clear. Does anyone has a suggestion how i could manage this with sass?

here is some snippet:

```
<div class="tabs">
<button class="tab"><button class="btn">1. Topic</button>
<button class="tab"><button class="btn">2. Topic</button>
<button class="tab"><button class="btn">3. Topic</button>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tabs{
width: 100%;
display: flex;
justify-content: start;
align-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tab{
&:first-child:not(:last-child) {
.btn {
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
}
&:last-child:not(:first-child) {
.btn {
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
border-top-left-radius: 0;
}
}
&:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
.btn {
border-radius: 0px;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Could you add some code that you've been tried please?

Comment: Using the css `:last-child` selector in SASS?

Comment: i would like to have the border-radius on the left and right side when there is one row. when the items in the navbar expand, and a second row is started the border-radius should be on only at the top of the first row and on the bottom of the second. Further, if there will be a third row, the middle row (second row) shouldnt have a border-radius. Hope iam clear enough :). thx for your help guys!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if this is possible unless you know how many items will be in each row at a given size. If you do, you could conditionally apply a class on the `.tabs` parent that determines which `.tab` child get what border radius

Comment: Thx LLai. I would like to keep 3 tabs in one row. Afterwards the tabs could expand.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit hairy, but I will try my best to break it down here. You can basically use five different selectors to select every case you need, which are:

1. The first item.
2. The third item.
3. The last item.
4. The first item of the last row.
5. The last item of the last full row.

The first item always needs a border radius in the top left corner, no matter what, so let's add that.

```
.tab {
  &:first-child .btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  }
}
```

The third item is always going to be the top right corner of the whole list (but the top right corner of the list isn't always going to be the third item, I will get back to that), so another easy selector to add.

```
.tab {
  &:first-child .btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) .btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  }
}
```

The last item of the list always needs a bottom right border radius.

```
.tab {
  &:first-child .btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) .btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:last-child .btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  }
}
```

Now for the not so self-explanatory part. We need to select the first item of the last row. Knowing we have three items in each row, selecting the *first item of every row* is done using `:nth-child(3n - 2)`. This selects the first, fourth, seventh, and so forth.

We need to combine that with a `:nth-last-child` pseudo-class in order to exclude the items that are not in the last row. `:nth-last-child(-n + 3)` will select the last three items, so if we combine the two, we have ourselves a solution.

```
.tab {
  &:first-child .btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) .btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:last-child .btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3n - 2):nth-last-child(-n + 3) .btn {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  }
}
```

So far so good, but one more step to go. We have applied `border-radius` to all four corners now, but still need to make sure that the last item of every full row get a `border-bottom-right-radius`.

That means you need to select every third item with `:nth-child(3n)` and *filter* the results to the last three items using `:nth-last-child(-n + 3)` from our previous example.

```
.tab {
  &:first-child .btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) .btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:last-child .btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3n - 2):nth-last-child(-n + 3) .btn {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3n):nth-last-child(-n + 3) .btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  }
}
```

And just to make sure our list looks good when it has *less than three items*, let's ˙border-top-right-radius` to the last item *if it is in the first row*, so either the first or second item.

```
.tab {
  &:first-child .btn {
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) .btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:last-child .btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3n - 2):nth-last-child(-n + 3) .btn {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(3n):nth-last-child(-n + 3) .btn {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  }
  &:nth-child(-n + 2):last-child .btn {
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  }
}
```

I created a [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/pentzzsolt/pen/ejerRJ?editors=0100) to help understand the items you need to select and the rules that you need to apply. Feel free to play around with the number of items in the list.